# How to write $\frac{k}{k}$ using $\sum$ notation?

Tags: notation

I want to use $\sum$ notation for this:$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k}+\ldots +\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k}}_{k\text{ times}}$$
I guessed$$\sum_1^k\frac{1}{k} ,$$but it equals $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: I often see $\sum^n{x}$ as a shorthand for $\sum_{i=1}^n{x}$, but in some contexts it could be ambiguos(e.g. in computer science indexes usually start at $0$, but you can disambiguate once at the beginning).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are getting confused because you are not being explicit about [the index of the summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Notation).

The summation
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{k}$$
**does** represent
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}}_{k\text{ times}}.$$
You're confusing this with the summation
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i}$$
which represents
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: Many many thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{k}.$$

Unless you want to multiply them in which case write

$$\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{k}.$$

Why you want to do this, in any case, is beyond me.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1i=1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{k-1}+\frac1k\quad\text{vs}\quad\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1k=\frac1k+\frac1k+\cdots+\frac1k+\frac1k=1$$

Comment: You are welcome.